# Implement "show more, show less" in React component when using map for adding the components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, show-hide

Having this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './style.scss';

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  return (
      <div className="main-div">
        {data.map((event, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="child-div">
            {event.message}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
  );
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array
};

export default MyComponent;
```

There is a div for the whole component, having the class `main-div`. For each element we receive through props (`data`) we are creating a child, having the class `child-div`.

My question is:

Is there a way to show only the first `child-div` when the component is rendered, put a button "Show more" - and when this is clicked to show all the child divs? And the button name to change to "Show less" - when clicked again to return to initial state?

I have found some implementations of something similar but don't know how to put it to this structure. Here it is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-truncate-show-more-show-less-vokho?file=/src/index.js:1188-1192).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `state` to filter/slice your data:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './style.scss';

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)
  const dataForDisplay = expanded ? data : data.slice(0, 10)
  return (
      <div className="main-div">
        {dataForDisplay.map((event, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="child-div">
            {event.message}
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>
          {expanded ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'} 
        </button>
      </div>
  );
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array
};

export default MyComponent;
```